# Which non-Schengen Countries can I visit with EU Blue Card?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, german-residents, blue-card

I have an Indian passport and am currently living and working in Germany holding an EU Blue card (Aufenthaltstitel). 
Which non-schengen countries can I visit without applying for a Visa explicitly?
I like to travel a lot, but planning in advance is not my strong suit. Therefore, want to know my options.

Comment: There's no resource where something like this would be compiled and is therefore quite a broad question. You must have at least a few countries in mind, could you name some?

Comment: It’s relatively easy to find a list of countries for which your citizenship allows visa-free or visa on arrival entry eg https://www.passportindex.org/ AFAIK there’s no consolidated resource that would give you the same information for your passport/residence card combination. If you have specific destinations in mind you can check via eg Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

Comment: @Traveller, the question is about the extra rights a Schengen long-stay visa gives. One might guess that these are all those which allow entry for short-stay visa holders, plus perhaps a few more?